# Allowing $ character in a property file managed by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a property file with the name `setting.properties`, and the following content:

```
authentication.provider=${Home_Url}/idm/names.lst
```

I am using this file via the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` within the `Spring` framework, as following:

```
<bean id="acl.authentication.provider" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${authentication.provider}"/>
</bean>
```

but when I initialize the above context I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'acl.authentication.provider#0' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'Home_Url'

My question is: Is there a way that values in property files can contains a `$` character, when they are to be processed using the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround would be to configure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with its `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` property set to `true`, which will cause it to ignore plcaeholders it can't resolve instead of failing with an exception.  Alternatively, change the `placeholderPrefix` to something else, e.g. `@{`, and then use

```
<constructor-arg index="0" value="@{authentication.provider}"/>
```